# Doctrine ORM ArrayCollection in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I noticed some weird things using Doctrine ORM's `ArrayCollection` in a PostgreSQL database (using this in a Symfony 3 project).

Take my `User` class with roles, It's initiated with a default role `ROLE_USER` and must be of type `array`.

```
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles->add('ROLE_USER');
    }
}
```

This is stored in the database as follows.

`O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"`

Which will give a `Serialization` error when trying to logon as a `User` because clearly part of the `ArrayCollection` is missing in the database.

After googling for a solution I came across [this Github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4029). As I understand it, it's a bug and you can't use the `ArrayCollection` in a `PostgreSQL` environment.

Not defining the type in the `@ORM\Column` tag doesn't help either, it then stores the following in the database and `Symfony` can't work with it to retrieve roles. `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000002300d10300000000545301a6`
And using `simple_array` or `json` as type doesn't return an object so both are no-go's

Does anyone have a workaround or solution for this? I'm really starting to regret switching from `MySQL` to `PostgreSQL`

NOTE: the code was working fine in `MySQL`, I just switched databases.

Comment: What would the JSON normally look like in the database? The full string I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your own mapping-type specially for ArrayCollection properties. The Doctrine [DBAL docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types) and [ORM cookbook](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) describe how to create one. The [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#full-default-configuration) describes how to activate/register it.

You could for example extract the array and json-encode it when converting to a DB value:

```
json_encode($value->toArray())
```

And json-decode and wrap it back into an ArrayCollection when converting to a PHP value:

```
new ArrayCollection(json_decode($value))
```

But it's your mapping type, you can do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem myself, I'm not sure exactly why postgresql truncates the serialized string, even tho the field is marked as text. My suggestion is that you convert the column type to json_array because postgresql has a native type for that. Else you can also use custom types which